# C++ HTTP web server library

Tags: c++, json, webserver

I need some help in selecting a http web server for an embedded system running Linux. Programming language is C++.
The server receives request and needs to respond in JSON format. I was looking at libmicrohttpd and libjson. 
Any other libraries I can use? 
I am new to web service related area, so what are the general consideration one should have when selecting a web server library?

Comment: **Off-topic** since asking for resources, but consider also [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) for HTTP service, and [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) for JSON

Answer (score 4):

I think the C++ project Drogon is what you want. [Drogon on github](https://github.com/an-tao/drogon)

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at `libcex`.

https://github.com/patrickjane/libcex

- C++11
- Clean/simple API
- Underlying eventloop model for scaling/performance (`libevent`/`libevhtp`)
- HTTP/HTTPS
- Out of the box security considerations
- cmake build system

Disclaimer: I am the author of the lib.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft C++ REST SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk)

- JSON
- C++11
- Async
- ...

Comment: This isn't detailed enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [RESTinio](https://bitbucket.org/sobjectizerteam/restinio-0.3). It is header only, so it is easier to integrate it into your project. And also it uses ASIO for networking/async stuff, and you can run it on your own `asio::io_context` (`asio::io_service`)  that is used for other parts of the application, it might be vital for embedded domain.

For dealing with JSON have a look at [json_dto](https://github.com/ngrodzitski/json_dto) it works on top of [RapidJSON](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson). For sample code for RESTinio with JSON see this repo: [highloadcup2017](https://bitbucket.org/ngrodzitski/highloadcup2017).

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[Cutelyst](https://cutelyst.org)** a C++11 built with Qt, with one of the best positions on [TechEmpower Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/).

Even though it requires Qt 5.6+ a full CMS ([CMlyst](https://github.com/cutelyst/CMlyst)) uses around 6MB of RAM while serving around 3000 requests per seconds on a single core, since the target is an embedded system fits perfectly.